# Probability concept applied to DNA sequencing.

Tags: probability, statistics

Q: If an infinitely long DNA sequence is observed, can you determine the probability that an A occurs before G? You can recast this problem to ignore or eliminate all C's and T's.

My attempt: I started with a DNA sequence of 3 and let $P(A)=\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $P(G)=\dfrac{2}{3}$. This means I can have AGG, GAG, GGA. So P(A before a G) is $\dfrac{2}{3}$. So I said that one can determine the probability that an A occurs before a G if given an infinitely long sequence (since it worked with just 3-long sequence).

I believe this type of argument won't suffice. Is there a more formal and mathematical way to answer this question?

Comment: If we eliminate all the C's and T's, we just have to determine the first letter, which presumably is equally likely to be an A or a G.

Comment: Thank you. But what if P(A) and P(G) were given, say with values $p_A$ and $p_G$?

Comment: I think in this case you can say that the probability that the first letter is an A or a G is $p_A+p_G$, so the probability that it is an A would be $\frac{p_A}{p_A+p_G}$.

Comment: In the example above, you prescribed the probabilities and then gave examples of length 3 chains. But how are then related? Why can you not have AAG? Probability is not exactly equal to the outcome. Another thing is the context of your problem. DNA chain growth is affected by electronic interactions between the new bead (A,T,C,G) and the existing chain. Are you considering that?

Comment: As you've written it, an A will NOT occur before a G iff the sequence is all G's. However, the probability of getting all G's is zero, so you are guaranteed that at some point in the *infinite* chain, an A will precede a G, as long as $P(A)>0$. The same applies for G before A.